# TF2.13: Local rendezvous recv item cancelled

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

Since TF2.13 we see this warning using the Docker `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu`:

```
 tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:405] Local rendezvous recv item cancelled. Key hash:
```

It is repeating several times before training starts. Does anyone know what a 'local rendezvous' is and how we can avoid this message showing up?

I tried in TF2.12 (with the Docker from nvidia nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:23.05-tf2-py3) and didn't see this message.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the problem in TF2.13. I was not able to find details about the message or directly solve it, but since everything seems to be working just fine and there has been no solution for more than two months, I decided to mute this message (inevitably with others of same or lower level) by setting min. log level for TF using:

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "1"
```

It is important to do this before importing TF.

Comment: get same here cc:421 .... and don't find the reason but trainning continu